# How to show text with several images in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android app that will be used to learn few technologies from tutorials. Each tutorial will contain several images distributed across the text. Same as like the tutorials we read on websites.

What logic I should use to implement this. The text and images will be fetched from local database.

Comment: If you don't need click event for text or image particularly then you can use taxtview with drawable by setting direction like left, top, right, bottom and text will be in center

Answer (score 0):

Check these links for [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) in android.To have images in between you need to properly place imageviews between textviews. If you want to add images dynamically and if you are not sure about the number of images you are going to add, build your layout in Activity(or Fragment) class not using xml.

Answer (score 0):

Make html pages out of them and use a WebView to display the html.